# jQuery Fullscreen Overlay Effect only works once

Tags: jquery

I'm coding a *Fullscreen Overlay Effect* by following Codrops [recent tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/). However, since I don't use the Modernizr-plugin, which the jQuery-script does, I tried removing it from the code. It works, but only *once*. When I close the overlay the button doesn't work anymore until I refresh the page.

You can see the example live at my clients website, which is currently in development - http://www.sk-inspection.com. Click the navigation point "Kontakt" to see it in action.

The jQuery I have:

```
(function() {
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
    overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    }

function toggleOverlay() {
    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
        classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
        };
    }
    else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
        classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
    }
}

triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

The original jQuery from Codrops tutorial:

```
(function() {
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
    overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

function toggleOverlay() {
    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
        classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
        };
        if( support.transitions ) {
            overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        }
        else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
        }
    }
    else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
        classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
    }
}

triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

And finally Classie.js, which is a class helper function.

```
    /*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

Comment: And what is `classie`, Lassie's cousin ?

Comment: It's plausible, @adeneo! The original post has been updated.

Comment: Does your console say anything the second time?

Comment: No, @Charlie. Nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included Modernizer like used in the original example supplied by Codrops.